# Copy and paste a file 200 times with new names

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, copy-paste

I have a folder with a file named: `'template.xlsx'`, and hundreds of files named:

- `old_2301 Item 1.xlsx`
- `old_2014 Item 2.xlsx`
- `old_5321 Item 3.xlsx`
- ...
- `old_3212 Item 200.xlsx`

I want to copy the file `template.xksx` and create 200 new files:

- `2301 Item 1.xlsx`
- `2014 Item 2.xlsx`
- `5321 Item 3.xlsx`
- `3212 Item 200.xlsx`

---

I've tried something like:

In the folder, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Right shift: select "open command-window here"

```
for %a in (*.*) do copy "template.xlsx" ... ren ...?
```

I want to rename the copied `template.xlsx` files to the same name as the other files, but with `old_` trimmed away.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Unless you need to redistribute the code that does this, I'd strongly suggest learning some Python. The code is much simpler, hence faster to write, easier to read, and less prone to bugs. I have colleagues trying to do fancy stuff in bash, it usually ends in headaches.

Comment: @Davidmh Why learn python when it is a trivial task for a batch file? In addition, Windows 7 does not come with python or bash installed.

Comment: @DavidPostill my point is that in Python it is easier, more readable, and more easily extended, at the cost of learning a bit of a new language (at this level, should be easy for a competent programmer like the OP), and installing it (which is easy enough, if you don't care about distributing it). And while the original task may be trivial, in my experience people will try to expand it, make it incrementally more complicated, and end up in a horrible mess of awk and sed (or whatever equivalent on Windows are), while Python helps to tame the complexity.

Comment: Also, I am not recommending bash, I consider it in the same category as batch. I mentioned it because my colleagues and me work on Linux.

Comment: @Davidmh I see no reason to use Python in a Windows shop. PowerShell provides much of the same "easy to learn"-ness but is more portable (Vista+ should work with the scripts) and the syntax IMO is even better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### I want to copy `template.xlsx` to the name of the other files, with `old_` removed

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem get list of file names
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b old_*.xlsx`) do (
  rem save the filename
  set _name=%%i
  rem remove old_ from the name
  set _name=!_name:old_=!
  rem do the copy to the modified name
  copy "template.xlsx" "!_name!"
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.

Comment: Where should I type this code? How I run this code?

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing In a batch file, which can be in the directory of interest. Then run the batch file.

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing in case you don't know how to create a batch file: You can type/paste the text in a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++ or whatever you like), and save it as `'filename.bat'` instead of `'filename.txt'`. Then you can just double-click and execute it as if it was a regular program (.exe).

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing [What Is A Batch File In Windows? How To Create A Batch File?](https://fossbytes.com/what-is-a-batch-file-in-windows-how-to-create-a-batch-file/)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the files named `old_*` as your name source and split at the underscore.

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%A in (
    'Dir /B /A-D "old_* Item *.xlsx"'
) Do Echo Copy template.xlsx "%%B"
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front of copy.

Explaining the parsing for /f options:

```
filename  old_2301 Item 1.xlsx
delims       _
tokens     1 _ * (rest)
for var   %%A %%B
```

A variant for the command line without batch:

```
For /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %A in ('Dir /B /A-D "old_*.xlsx"') Do Copy template.xlsx "%B"
```

Comment: I _guess_ this works as a charm, but I ended up using David's answer so I accepted his :) Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: Speedwiese there isn't a big difference as the copy will take up most of the time. Added a cmd line variant, no batch needed then.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I actually wanted a program that I could run over and over, if this is just a one-off or a few-off, I would use Notepad++ or any other text editor with block copy and paste.  Open a command prompt in the relevant directory and type `dir/b > 1.txt`, which results in e.g.:

```
D:\MiscJunk\1>type 1.txt
1.txt
old_2014 Item 2.txt
old_2301 Item 1.txt
old_5321 Item 3.txt
template.txt
```

Edit 1.txt in Notepad++ and add as many of these lines as needed:

```
copy template.txt ""
copy template.txt ""
copy template.txt ""
```

Block copy (Alt Shift arrow keys) the text:

```
2014 Item 2.txt
2301 Item 1.txt
5321 Item 3.txt
```

and paste it between the quotes:

```
copy template.txt "2014 Item 2.txt"
copy template.txt "2301 Item 1.txt"
copy template.txt "5321 Item 3.txt"
```

Then after checking the commands are correct and adjusting accordingly, just copy&paste those commands back into the command prompt, resulting in:

```
D:\MiscJunk\1>dir/b
2014 Item 2.txt
2301 Item 1.txt
5321 Item 3.txt
...
```

This method is ultra-simple with no debugging needed, and there's very little that can go wrong.  Knocking up blocks of commands in Notepad++ is something I do fairly regularly.

Comment: I used David's method first, but it turned out I had to rename them again... This was perfect the second time around :) Thanks a lot!